# Closed-form value for $\min_{x^T\Sigma x \le 1}\|x\|_1 - x^Ta$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $a \in \mathbb R^n$ and $\Sigma$ be a positive definite matrix of size $n$.

## Question

What is the closed-form value of

$$\min_{\|x\|_\Sigma \le 1}\|x\|_1 - x^Ta,
$$

where $\|x\|_\Sigma := \sqrt{x^T\Sigma x}$ is the norm induced by by the inner product $(x, y) \mapsto x^T\Sigma y$ ?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to believe such a closed form should exist?

Comment: Changed argmin ==> min.  About a compelling reason, the limiting case $\Sigma \rightarrow 0$ corresponds to the convex conjugate of $x \mapsto \|x\|_1$ evaluated at $a$. This evaluates to the indicator function of the $\ell_\infty$ unit ball. My question is just a "slight twist" to this problem.

Comment: This should be possible if $\Sigma$ is diagonal. Non-diagonal 'twists' tend to make this impossible.

Comment: A solution to a non-trivial special case, e.g the diagonal case $\Sigma = \text{diag}(\sigma_1^2,\ldots,\sigma_n^2)$, of the problem should already be very interesting. Please don't hesitate to write something down :)

Comment: Please try using Lagrange multiplier:  $L=\sum x_j - \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{a} - \lambda \mathbf{x}^T \Sigma \mathbf{x},$ and take the partial derivatives and set equal to zero:  $0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j}, \quad 0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}.$

Comment: Thanks to the helpful comments. Below, I've put together a solution which looks like the "best thing possible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been suggested in the comments that the solution value might not be analytically expressible in general, but that there is some hope, when the matrix $\Sigma$ is diagonal. I'm going to provide a solution hereunder. Also, I'm bad at using Lagrange multiplies (e.g I always screw up the signs, etc.). I'm going to attempt a more "synthetic" solution.

Now, using the dual representation of the $\ell_1$-norm, one has

> $$
> \begin{split}\alpha:=\min_{\|z\|_\Sigma \le 1} \|z\|_1 - z^Ta &= \min_{\|z\|_\Sigma \le 1}\max_{\|w\|_\infty \le 1}z^Tw-z^T a =\max_{\|w\|_\infty \le 1}\min_{\|z\|_\Sigma \le 1}z^T(w-a)\\
> &=\max_{\|w\|_\infty \le 1}-\left(\max_{\|z\|_\Sigma \le 1}-z^T(w-a)\right)=\max_{\|w\|_\infty \le 1}-\|w-a\|_{\Sigma^{-1}}\\
> &=-\min_{\|w\|_\infty \le 1}\|w-a\|_{\Sigma^{-1}},
> \end{split}
> $$

where I've used [Sion's minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem) to interchange min and max.
The above expression for the optimal objective value $\alpha$ is unlikely to be computable analytically in general, due to the non-separability of the objective (even though the constraint is perfectly separable as a product of 1D constraints).

> In any case, it follows from the above display that $\alpha \le 0$, with equality iff $\|a\|_\infty \le 1$.

## Exact formula for diagonal $\Sigma$

In the special case where $\Sigma=\text{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_2)$, the square of the optimal objective value $\alpha^2$ can be separated as

> $$
> \alpha \le 0,\;\alpha^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\min_{|w_i| \le 1}\sigma_i^{-2}(w_i-a_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^{-2}\begin{cases}(a_i+1)^2,&\mbox{ if }a_i \le -1,\\ 0,&\mbox{ if }-1 < a_i \le 1,\\ (a_i-1)^2,&\mbox{ if }a_i > 1,\end{cases}
> $$

which is indeed an analytical formula, albeit a very "hairy" one.

## Upper and lower bounds for general $\Sigma$

Let $\sigma_n \ge \ldots \ge \sigma_2 \ge \sigma_1 > 0$ be the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$. Then, one has
$$
\sigma_n^{-1}\|w-a\|_2 \le \|w-a\|_{\Sigma^{-1}} \le \sigma_1^{-1}\|w-a\|_2.
$$
Thus one has the bounds

> $-\sqrt{\gamma/\sigma_1} \le \alpha \le -\sqrt{\gamma/\sigma_n}$,
> where $\gamma := \sum_{i=1}^n\begin{cases}(a_i+1)^2,&\mbox{ if }a_i \le -1,\\ 0,&\mbox{ if }-1 < a_i \le 1,\\ (a_i-1)^2,&\mbox{ if }a_i > 1.\end{cases}$

Moreover, if $\|a\|_\infty > 1$, then it isn't hard to see that $\gamma \le n(\|a\|_\infty-1)$ (see details below), from where $\alpha \ge -\sqrt{\gamma/\sigma_1} \ge -\sqrt{n/\sigma_1}(\|a\|_\infty-1)$, which corresponds to a bound which has been observed by someone in the comments. However, by construction, this bound is potentially very loose.

---

Note that $a_i \le -1 \implies (a_i + 1)^2 \le (\|a\|_\infty - 1)^2$
and similarly $a_1 > 1 \implies 0 \le (a_i - 1)^2 \le (\|a\|_\infty-1)^2$. Thus $\gamma \le n(\|a\|_\infty-1)$.

Comment: what's the formal justification for switching $\min$ and $\max$ ?

Comment: Sion's minimax theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem.

Comment: Writing KKT conditions with the subdifferential variant, one sees that if $\|a\|_{\infty}\leq 1$, the min is $0$, and if $\|a\|_{\infty}> 1$, the min is $\geq -(\|a\|_{\infty}- 1)\sqrt{\frac{n}{\lambda_1}}$ where $\lambda_1$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $\Sigma$. I don't know how tight the last bound is.

Comment: Yes, your bound holds, but is very loose. It is a simplification of a tighter but slighter more complicated bound. See edit to my answer above.